How to bundle JSF pages in a separate Web Module in Jakarta EE9?
I am developing a Jakarta EE9 web application with maven. I wonder if it is possible to  separate a set of JSF Pages together with CDI Beans in a separate module that can be reused in other Web Applications?
I know that it is no problem to bundle CDI beans in a util jar-module to reuse it. But my goal is also to bundle JSF pages in such a module.
Is this somehow possible in Jakarta EE 9?
